# Return an array from mysqli stmt query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch, call-user-func-array

I'm trying to convert a site to use prepared mysql statements, however I'm having some trouble replacing my use of `fetch_array()`.

[The comments on php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php#82742) offer a solution which I would have thought should work but for some reason I'm getting strange undefined constant errors when calling a function via `call_user_func_array()` can someone suggest a better way of doing it?

Here's the function I'm using at the moment. I've dumbed it down a bit for posting on here (it's part of a larger class which extends mysqli and handles error catching etc) so sorry if I've made any mistakes copy and pasting it.

```
public static function stmt_bind_assoc(&$stmt, &$out) {
    $data = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
    $fields = array();
    $out = array();

    $fields[0] = $stmt;
    $count = 1;

    while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
        $fields[$count] = &$out[$field->name];
        $count++;
    }
    call_user_func_array(mysqli_stmt_bind_result, $fields);
}
```

```
public function fetch_array($rawQuery) {
    $stmt = $this->prepare($rawQuery);
    $row = array();
    self::stmt_bind_assoc($stmt, $row);
    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->free();
    return $result;
}
```

The errors I get are:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant mysqli_stmt_bind_result - assumed 'mysqli_stmt_bind_result'

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::free()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error comes from your `call_user_func_array` statement: you need quotes around the `mysqli_stmt_bind_result`, otherwise PHP assumes it's a constant.

And there's no `free()` function in `mysqli_stmt`, use `$stmt->free_result()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $servername = "localhost"; $username = "root"; $password = ""; $dbnam = "test";

 // Create connection $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 die("Connection failed: %s\n" . mysqli_connect_errno()); }

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT * FROM myguests") or
die(mysqli_error($conn));   mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

$data = mysqli_stmt_result_metadata($stmt);
$fields = array();
$out = array();

 $fields[0] = &$stmt;
 $count = 1;

 while($field = mysqli_fetch_field($data)) {
     $fields[$count] = &$out[$field->name];
     $count++;
 }

 call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_result", $fields);
 while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt))    print_r($out);

$stmt->close(); $conn->close();
```

Works great on me, hope it helps